# Looking for a way to get the first 30 seconds of audio from a video file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, file, audio, video, buffer

I'm trying to figure out a way to get an audio file of the first 30 seconds of a video file using Javascript within the context of a browser extension.

I've essentially already done this taking the video file, using `FileReader > readAsArrayBuffer` to get an `ArrayBuffer`, then `AudioContext.decodeAudioData` to get an `AudioBuffer`, and then [this method](https://miguelmota.com/bytes/slice-audiobuffer/) to slice the audio buffer.

However, I've found that `AudioContext.decodeAudioData` causes the Chrome tab to crash completely when the video is very long (several hours), so this approach might not be feasible.

I've been trying to find a way to instead slice the video file to the first 30 seconds, and *then* convert it to audio rather than convert the entire video file to audio first to get around the `decodeAudioData` issue. I also noticed there's some upper limit on file size with `readAsArrayBuffer` that I'd like to get around.

Of course, if there's any other possible solution outside of what I've described, I'd love to hear it. I've naturally come across `ffmpeg` often in my search, but I cannot seem to get the web assembly version to work in the context of the browser extension.